# Expectation value of spaces between items with the same color

Tags: probability

There are $30$ items, $20$ black and $10$ white and they are randomly organized in a line. I wish to find $E[x]$ where X is the number of spaces between objects with the same color. What I tried to do was:
$$X=\sum_{i=1}^{29}X_{i}$$
$$X_{i}\sim Ber\left(\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\right)=Ber\left(\frac{5}{9}\right)\implies E\left[X\right]=29\cdot\frac{5}{9}=\frac{145}{9}$$
Where $X_i$ is an indicator of a space being between two items of the same color. But the correct answer seems to be $47/3$, and I can't seem to find my mistake.

*Sorry, I edited a part that wasn't related.

Comment: Your mistake is that you treat these variables as independent variables, while in practice there is a relationship between them. For example, there is no situation where all the spaces are between items of the same color.

Comment: E[X] = E[X|Black]P(Black) + E[X|white]P(white), P(black) = 2/3, P(white) = 1/3. E[X|black]= (1)19/29+ 2(1-19/29)(19/28)+3(1-19/29)(1-19/28)(19/27) +4(1-19/29)(1-19/28)(1-19/27)(19/26)+...+11(1-19/29)(1-19/28)(1-19/27)...(1-19/20)*19/19.  Do the same for white.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on what you did here? Starting in the $E[x \mid \text{black}]$ calculation.

Comment: I believe you are talking about **runs** of black and white items. Counts of runs are widely used to test for randomness, so there are formulas for
the distributions of runs. For example, see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test). Or other articles or examples of runs test, [maybe this](https://ncss-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/themes/ncss/pdf/Procedures/NCSS/Analysis_of_Runs.pdf), depending on your interests.